# Carrinho php quantidade

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um carrinho feito em php e os produtos estão no banco de dados, como eu faço para colocar uma restrição no em um determinado produto por exemplo:
O produto número 4 do meu banco de dados quero que a quantidade dele só vá até 100.
Obrigado quem poder ajudar.

Comment: Você quer essa restrição na camada de negócios, banco de cados ou ambos?

Comment: Os produtos do carrinho são colocados la pelo id do banco de dados, quero essa restrição por id para quando for calcular o frete pelo web service dos correios, deu para entender? 

Obrigado

Comment: E porque voce nao cria um campo na tabela para os limites de cada produto? Por exemplo, produto id= 4 - limite 100, produto id= 5 - limite 200?

Comment: É não tinha pensado em por o limite boa ideia vou testar, eu já consegui fazer as comparações das caixas valeu mesmo a todos, agora falta colocar o limit na quantidade de cada produto.
Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso via software, crie um campo com a quantidade de cada produto e seu máximo no banco de dados.

Quando você for fazer as consultas, faça uma busca no banco e verifique se o limite já foi atingido e tenha o controle necessário.

Outra maneira é fazer um procedimento no seu banco de dados para ser executado antes de cada insert. Se a tabela tiver disponibilidade, insere. Caso contrário, envia um aviso e não insere. Depende do banco, mas geralmente isso pode ser feito usando PL/SQL.